# How are 14-bit memory addresses accessed?

Tags: c, memory-address

I know that each two letters in a hexdecimal address represents a byte, meaning that 0xFFFF is a 16bit address and can represent 65,536 bytes of memory, if the system is byte-addressable. However, if talking about a number of bits that is not a multiple of 8 (such as 14bit address), how can the operating system represnt these addresses?

```
0xFFFF -> 16 bit (e.g. Virtual memory address)
14 bit -> 0xFFF ? (Physical memory address)
```

One might say that the system has to be not byte addressable to access a not multiple of 8 address.. Then what will it be? I want the 16 bit of the virtual address to be byte addressable so we can easily access the data stored at that address, and I want to represent it in *C* code, but I have trouble representing the 14 bit physical memory addresses.

```c
#define MAX_VIRT_ADDR   ((0xffff) - 1) /* 65,536 */
#define MAX_PHYS_ADDR   ((?) - 1) /* Max of 14bit physical memory space */
```

Comment: I would be 65536 physical addresses as well. Is there any particular reason why you need to worry about 14 bit/byte systems, since such systems barely exist in the real world?

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up the size of the address (14 bits) with the size of bytes (presumably still 8 bits).

Comment: How would you do it in decimal, of you have only, let's say, 30 item to index? Correct, you limit your numbers to [0, 29]. The same way you can use [0x0000, 0x3FFF]. Or what is your issue?

Comment: @Lundin _Is there any particular reason why you need to worry about 14 bit/byte systems_ - I try to implement a specific topic in memory management.

Comment: @PaulHankin - My system is byte addressable and the size of one byte is 8, so I have hard time having a `uint14_t` data type for me to able to represent 14 bit addresses.

Comment: Why are you using an integer type for a pointer instead of a pointer type? Note that it's normal for not all addresses to be valid. On my home PC pointers are 64 bits, but I don't have 18.4 exabytes of memory.

Comment: @PaulHankin Why would I waste 8 bytes if I only need 14 bits?

Comment: Why would a pointer be 8 bytes for a system with only 16k of RAM? Typically, a pointer will be 16 bits for those sorts of systems. In C all values have a size that's a multiple of bytes, so (assuming 8bit bytes), uint14_t if it existed would be represented as a 2-byte value with some representations meaningless.

Comment: @PaulHankin I feel like you don't follow me, I don't see how a system will be able to access a 14 bit address with pointer of size 16 bits or anything else. To makek my Q more clear, how did old operating systems accessed 14 bit memory addresses?

Comment: @PaulHankin _My_ system uses pointer of size 8 bytes, and I make a program that simulates a 14 bit physical address space, hence I can't use _my system_ pointer size to represent pointers to _my program_ physical memory or _virtual_ memory.

Comment: They had 16-bit pointers and you had to access only memory that existed.

Comment: @PaulHankin _They had 16-bit pointers and you had to access only memory that existed._ - Oh okay, that doesn't make sense (Did they really do that? D:) but answers one of my questions, thank you.

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information in the question to get satisfactory answers. If you're writing an emulator on a PC (which I guess from your comments you are), that's very different from writing a program that runs on a machine with 14-bit addresses.

Comment: @PaulHankin yes, I see my question is not that clear, close it. I think I know how to continue with the information you people provided me.

Comment: I think a lot of people have forgotten (or been born after) the time when we had 16-bit addresses with _near_ and _far_ pointers, extended memory emulation _etc_. Back in the day, programs had to do a lot of the stuff that we now take for granted in modern operating systems.

Comment: To make this question a valuable one, please [edit] it and elaborate on the underlying problem. It is not clear from the question or from your comments what the issue is.

Comment: Think about a famous microcontroller of former times, the PIC 16F84. It has 1K words of program memory each 14 bits wide, so 10 bits for an address. However, hex numbers can be used for machine code and addresses.

Comment: This code and comment don't match: `((0xffff) - 1) /* 65,536 */`

Answer (score 3):

The addresses are still just numbers. On a system with a 14-bit address bus, they go from 00000000000000 (binary) up to 11111111111111 (binary).

We can also write those numbers in decimal: they go from 0 up to 16383.

Or we can write them in hexadecimal: they go from 0 up to 3FFF (or 0000 up to 3FFF).

Or in octal: they go from 0 up to 37777 (or 00000 up to 37777).

Or in any other system we like.

---

Typically a system based on 8-bit bytes will allow 2 bytes to be used to access a memory address. If the system has some kind of memory protection unit, and it's configured appropriately, then addresses above 3FFF may cause some kind of invalid address exception (i.e. a segfault). Otherwise, usually the extra bits are just ignored, so that no matter whether the program accesses "address" 0x0005, 0x4005, 0x8005, or 0xC005, the actual address sent to the address bus is 5 (binary: 00000000000101).

Answer (score 1):

Your maximum "virtual" 16-bit address is `0xFFFF`.  Your maximum "physical" 14-bit address is `0x3FFF`.

There's no rule that says address sizes have to be powers of 2, or that they have to be the same size as the words being addressed.  It's *massively more convenient* to do things that way, but not required.

The old Motorola 68K had 32-bit words but a 24-bit address bus - address values were stored in 32-bit words with the upper 8 bits left unused.

As for mapping your 16-bit "virtual" address space onto a 14-bit "physical" address space, treat the upper two bits in the virtual address as a page number, treat the lower 14 bits as the offset into the page, map them directly to "physical" addresses.  Store in a 16-bit type like `uint16_t`, then use macros to extract page number and address like so:

```
#define PAGENO(vaddr)   ((0xC000 & vaddr) >> 14)
#define PHADDR(vaddr)   (0x3FFF & vaddr)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: your 14bit address is

```
struct {
    unsigned addr : 14;
};
```

You simply ignore 2 bits of the 16bit value.

Another way is to sign extend the 14bit value to 16bit. That's what 64bit systems like AMD64 or ARM64 do. They have 43-56 bits address space depending on the CPU and that is sign extended to 64bit. Addresses where the top bits aren't all 0 or all 1 are illegal.

Answer (score -1):

Exotic systems where bytes have more than 8 bits still (as far as I know) use the same addressing on byte level. Only the size of a byte changes. Certain digital signal processors like this do exist in the real world, although those would not run on an OS but get coded as "bare metal". Traditionally, DSP programming is also most often done in assembler rather than C.

So for any system with 16 bit wide address bus, you'll have:

```
#define MAX_VIRT_ADDR  0xffffu /* 65,535 */
#define MAX_PHYS_ADDR  0xffffu /* 65,535 */
```

And the size of one byte is irrelevant. If you'd design the system in any other way, you'd probably lose the advantage of having a larger byte size.

Comment: This wouldn't fit my concept, e.g. paging when addressing 16 bit virtual address to 14 bit physical address, `MAX_PHYS_ADDR` is too much and do not fit 14bit addresses, same when I need to have a data type for 14 bit, such as `uint14_t`

Comment: @BoyimAndresa How many times do I need to tell you that the number of bits in a byte will not matter? In general, there is no obvious relation between the size of the (biggest) chunk of data that a CPU can access in a single instruction and the size of the address bus. If you are designing a 4 lane highway, then that doesn't somehow enforce a magic constraint on how long that highway can become.

Comment: Now as it happens even some of the super-restrained 4 bit MCUs use 16 bit addressing as an option. Regarding efficiency, low-end MCUs typically have instruction support for a limited address range known as _zero page_, where it may access data a tiny bit faster than elsewhere.